# Shopify Scripts - How to exclude customers with tag from tiered discount?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I have a Shopify script I've pieced together that applies 30% discount for customers with the tag "VIP", but I'm also going to be running a promotion for tiered product discounts and I don't want this to apply to those customers tagged "VIP". In other words, the two promotions need to run independent of each other - VIP customers should NOT get 30% off on top of the tiered promotion.

I know I need to set the customer_tag_match_type as :exclude and the customer_tags as ["VIP"], which I have done, but I'm sure there needs to be something in the TieredProductDiscountByProductSpendCampaign class to run a check on this and as I'm new to this, I'm not sure what that needs to be.

Can anyone help?

```
# ================================ Customizable Settings 
================================
# ================================================================
# Product Discounts by Customer Tag
#
# ================================================================
DISCOUNTS_FOR_VIP_TAG = [
  {
    customer_tag_match_type: :include,
    customer_tags: ["VIP"],
    product_selector_match_type: :include,
    product_selector_type: :all,
    product_selectors: nil,
    discount_type: :percent,
    discount_amount: 30,
    discount_message: "Enjoy 30% off as a VIP",
  },
]
# ================================ Customizable Settings 
================================
# ================================================================
# Tiered Product Discount by Product Spend Threhsold
#
# ================================================================
PRODUCT_DISCOUNT_TIERS = [
  {
    customer_tag_match_type: :exclude,
    customer_tags: ["VIP"],
    tiers: [
      {
        threshold: 200,
        discount_type: :percent,
        discount_amount: 15,
        discount_message: 'Spend $200 and get 15% off!',
      },
      {
        threshold: 400,
        discount_type: :percent,
        discount_amount: 20,
        discount_message: 'Spend $400 and get 20% off!',
      },
      {
        threshold: 600,
        discount_type: :percent,
        discount_amount: 25,
        discount_message: 'Spend $600 and get 25% off!',
      },
    ],
  },
]
# ================================ Script Code (do not edit) 
================================
# ================================================================
# CustomerTagSelector
#
# Finds whether the supplied customer has any of the entered tags.
# ================================================================
class CustomerTagSelector
  def initialize(match_type, tags)
    @comparator = match_type == :include ? 'any?' : 'none?'
    @tags = tags.map { |tag| tag.downcase.strip }
  end

  def match?(customer)
    customer_tags = customer.tags.map { |tag| tag.downcase.strip }
    (@tags & customer_tags).send(@comparator)
  end
end

# ================================================================
# ProductSelector
#
# Finds matching products by the entered criteria.
# ================================================================
class ProductSelector
  def initialize(match_type, selector_type, selectors)
    @match_type = match_type
    @comparator = match_type == :include ? 'any?' : 'none?'
    @selector_type = selector_type
    @selectors = selectors
  end

  def match?(line_item)
    if self.respond_to?(@selector_type)
      self.send(@selector_type, line_item)
    else
      raise RuntimeError.new('Invalid product selector type')
    end
  end

  def tag(line_item)
    product_tags = line_item.variant.product.tags.map { |tag| tag.downcase.strip }
    @selectors = @selectors.map { |selector| selector.downcase.strip }
    (@selectors & product_tags).send(@comparator)
  end

  def type(line_item)
    @selectors = @selectors.map { |selector| selector.downcase.strip }
    (@match_type == :include) == @selectors.include? 
   (line_item.variant.product.product_type.downcase.strip)
  end

  def vendor(line_item)
    @selectors = @selectors.map { |selector| selector.downcase.strip }
    (@match_type == :include) == @selectors.include? 
   (line_item.variant.product.vendor.downcase.strip)
  end

  def product_id(line_item)
    (@match_type == :include) == @selectors.include?(line_item.variant.product.id)
  end

  def variant_id(line_item)
    (@match_type == :include) == @selectors.include?(line_item.variant.id)
  end

  def subscription(line_item)
    !line_item.selling_plan_id.nil?
  end

  def all(line_item)
    true
  end
end

# ================================================================
# DiscountApplicator
#
# Applies the entered discount to the supplied line item.
# ================================================================
class DiscountApplicator
  def initialize(discount_type, discount_amount, discount_message)
    @discount_type = discount_type
    @discount_message = discount_message

    @discount_amount = if discount_type == :percent
      1 - (discount_amount * 0.01)
    else
      Money.new(cents: 100) * discount_amount
    end
  end

  def apply(line_item)
    new_line_price = if @discount_type == :percent
      line_item.line_price * @discount_amount
    else
      [line_item.line_price - (@discount_amount * line_item.quantity), Money.zero].max
    end

    line_item.change_line_price(new_line_price, message: @discount_message)
  end
end

# ================================================================
# DiscountForCustomerTagCampaign
#
# If we have a matching customer (by tag), the entered discount
# is applied to any matching items.
# ================================================================
class DiscountForCustomerTagCampaign
  def initialize(campaigns)
    @campaigns = campaigns
  end

  def run(cart)
    return unless cart.customer&.tags

    @campaigns.each do |campaign|
      customer_tag_selector = CustomerTagSelector.new(campaign[:customer_tag_match_type], campaign[:customer_tags])

      next unless customer_tag_selector.match?(cart.customer)

      product_selector = ProductSelector.new(
        campaign[:product_selector_match_type],
        campaign[:product_selector_type],
        campaign[:product_selectors]
      )

      discount_applicator = DiscountApplicator.new(
        campaign[:discount_type],
        campaign[:discount_amount],
        campaign[:discount_message]
      )

      cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
        next unless product_selector.match?(line_item)
        discount_applicator.apply(line_item)
      end
    end
  end
end

# ================================================================
# TieredProductDiscountByProductSpendCampaign
#
# If the total amount spent on matching items is greather than (or
# equal to) an entered threshold, the associated discount is
# applied to each matching item.
# ================================================================
class TieredProductDiscountByProductSpendCampaign
  def initialize(campaigns)
    @campaigns = campaigns
  end

  def run(cart)
    @campaigns.each do |campaign|  
      if campaign[:product_selector_type] == :all
        total_applicable_cost = cart.subtotal_price
        applicable_items = cart.line_items
      else
        product_selector = ProductSelector.new(
          campaign[:product_selector_match_type],
          campaign[:product_selector_type],
          campaign[:product_selectors],
        )

        applicable_items = cart.line_items.select { |line_item| product_selector.match?(line_item) }

        next if applicable_items.nil?

        total_applicable_cost = applicable_items.map(&:line_price).reduce(Money.zero, :+)
      end

      tiers = campaign[:tiers].sort_by { |tier| tier[:threshold] }.reverse
      applicable_tier = tiers.find { |tier|  total_applicable_cost >= (Money.new(cents: 100) * tier[:threshold]) }

      next if applicable_tier.nil?

      discount_applicator = DiscountApplicator.new(
        applicable_tier[:discount_type],
        applicable_tier[:discount_amount],
        applicable_tier[:discount_message]
      )

      applicable_items.each do |line_item|
        discount_applicator.apply(line_item)
      end
    end
  end
end

CAMPAIGNS = [
  TieredProductDiscountByProductSpendCampaign.new(PRODUCT_DISCOUNT_TIERS),
  DiscountForCustomerTagCampaign.new(DISCOUNTS_FOR_VIP_TAG),
]

CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
  campaign.run(Input.cart)
end

Output.cart = Input.cart
```

Comment: You know scripts are dead and will no longer work in a few months? Instead, you probably want to focus your effort on using a Function, as they are the first-class citizens in the customer discounting world now. Why waste a minute on this Script when you know it is DOA?